# Правильно ли будет если я в Laravel все внешние ключи базы данных добавлю отдельной миграцией?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть много таблиц с перекрестными внешними ключами  для уменьшения ошибок решил вывести их в отдельную миграцию

```
2119_09_20_114857_add_foreign_keys.php
```

Правильная ли это практика ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда приложение никогда не было в продакшене и команда разработчиков довольно мала, я думаю лучшим решением было бы рефакторинг всех миграций по одной для каждой таблицы, включая все поля и внешние ключи, затем попросить всех сбросить и воссоздать базу данных. Это позволяет избежать проблем с существующими данными при добавлении ключей и делает проект чистым, полегче в понимании/дебагу для миграций. Возможно, сделайте db-dump только данных (а не структуры) перед этим рефакторингом, чтобы восстановить его после или, возможно, сделать для этого 
dev seeder'ы.

Если приложение находится в производстве или это решение не подходит для команды разработчиков. Просто добавьте внешние ключи непосредственно в новую миграцию, но не изменяйте временную метку, это может иметь непредвиденные последствия, и она должна работать нормально, если все будет постепенно возрастать. Убедитесь, что откат включает удаление ключей.

Можете попробовать этот пакет: https://github.com/stidges/laravel-fk-migration